# Service Level Inheritance

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, service, composition

Assume we have 2 modes of Service.

> ICommonInterface
>     -action1()
>
> Mode1Service inherits ICommonInterface
>   Mode2Service inherits ICommonInterface

Both have similar functionality, so have a common interface (ICommonInterface). So what would be best way to provide implementation for ICommonInterface, would it be to have inheritance or composition or any other way ?

1) This is not purely a inheritance, if we prefer composition.
The common logic would go as a different helper class. Mode1Service and Mode2Service would have to obey the common contract and call these helper to provide actual implementation.
    - Helper class need not be usable seperately.

2) By inheritance, we would have a AbstractBaseModeService which inherits common interface which is inherited by both the Mode service classes.
   Again, Mode1Service and Mode2Service will have its own interfaces apart from common interface.

I feel inheritance is better even though it only provides code reusability. Any ideas on how to handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I will also prefer something like this:

```
class CCommonFunctions
{
   public:
    // Some utility Functions
    void set_somefunctions() 
    {
    }
};

class ICommonInterface
{
  public:
    virtual void action() = 0;
  protected:
    CCommonFunctions *p;
};

class Mode1Service: public ICommonInterface
{
   public: 
     void action() 
     {
        p->set_somefunctions();
        ... 
     }
};

class ServiceMaker
{
 public:
   void setService(ICommonInterface *icip)
   {
       m_ici = icip;
   }
   void makeAction()
   {
       m_ici ->action();
       ...
   }  
 private:
   ICommonInterface *m_ici;
};

int main()
{
  ServiceMaker mk;
  ICommonInterface *ici = new Mode1Service;

  mk.setService(ici);
  mk.makeAction();
  ...
  ...
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you, I have also used Builder pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

1. Should we keep the objects DRY (Dont' repeat ourselves),
2. Should these implementations follow a common contract.

I personally feel that we can proceed with interface and abstract methods that would have those common logic and have implementations do their own stuff wherever required. This is the default way. Pulling it as a helper class or domain object from the abstract class by composing a new object is also good.

The example what [Saby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571180/saby) had provided is the same I would replicate.

*Disclaimer: (Could have been considered)*
Just because `Mode1Service` and `Mode2Service` has something in common pulling out a common interface `ICommonInterface` would be bad, coz interfaces came in for the purpose of making the services to follow some constructs.